# Throttling in Swift without going reactive

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, throttling

Is there a simple way of implementing the Throttle feature in Reactive programming without having to use RxSwift or similar frameworks.

I have a textField delegate method that I would like not to fire every time a character is inserted/deleted.

How to do that using vanilla Foundation?

Comment: The delegate will fire every time. In your delegate method you can start a timer. If the delegate fires again before the timer goes off, restart the timer. When the timer goes off, do whatever you need to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it is possible to achieve.

But first lets answer small question what is Throttling?

> In software, a throttling process, or a throttling controller as it is
> sometimes called, is a process responsible for regulating the rate at
> which application processing is conducted, either statically or
> dynamically.

Example of the [Throttling](https://gist.github.com/pixelspark/50afabc9ce29412cca7ef6d6323da7de) function in the Swift.

In case that you have describe with delegate method you will have issue that delegate method will be called each time. So I will write short example how it impossible to do in the case you describe.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var timer: Timer?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.delegate = self
    }
    
    @objc func validate() {
        print("Validate is called")
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        timer?.invalidate()
        
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.validate), userInfo: nil, repeats: false);
        
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: `timer?.invalidate()` is a bit simpler.

Comment: I think this will do for now. The problem with using just a timer is: with every new timer the selector is executed **without** cancelling the previous call. and this would defeat the whole point. And there would be no guarantee that the calls to the selector are in the assumed order.

Comment: @Carpsen90 You don't actually need them to be in a particular order. You just need to ignore all the previous results. The way this should be done depends on your API. I am usually passing some context along the request with the text inside the context. When the request completes, I can compare that the current text is the same that the one we requested.

Comment: In other words, the selector should be cancelable. I'll have a look.

Comment: Isn't this a debounce function? A throttle function, wouldn't always trigger `0.5` from the last textField input. Instead it would always trigger at `0.5` regardless of whether the user has input new characters or not.

Answer (score 2):

- disclaimer: I am a writer.

[Throttler](https://github.com/boraseoksoon/Throttler) can be the right katana to make you happy.

You can do debounce and throttle without going reactive programming using Throttler like,

```swift
import Throttler

// advanced debounce, running a first task immediately before initiating debounce.

for i in 1...1000 {
    Throttler.debounce {
        print("debounce! > \(i)")
    }
}

// debounce! > 1
// debounce! > 1000


// equivalent to debounce of Combine, RxSwift.

for i in 1...1000 {
    Throttler.debounce(shouldRunImmediately: false) {
        print("debounce! > \(i)")
    }
}

// debounce! > 1000
```

Throttler also can do advanced debounce, running a first event immediately before initiating debounce that Combine and RxSwift don't have by default.

You could, but you may need a complex implementation yourself for that.